# How to separate the execution of an HTTP request from the parsing of the HTTP response body using Spring WebClient?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webclient

I want to separate the execution of an HTTP request from the parsing of the HTTP response body using Spring `WebClient`.

I want to write tests that test each of these concerns separately so that I can easily identify where an issue exists (in the execution of the request or in the parsing of the response body). I don't want the request call to fail because the response was a primitive string even though I was expecting JSON.

`WebClient` only seems to be able to execute a request and parse the response's body in one step:

```
var responseBody = client.get().uri(endpoint).retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

I want to do something like this:

```
var response = client.get().uri(endpoint).retrieve().block();
var responseBody = response.bodyToMono(String.class).block();
```

Comment: I think it would be better if you can provide a sample code referring to your query, to avoid any ambiguity

Comment: I added a code sample.